# ISR in .cpp file not found

Tags: c++, gcc, embedded, interrupt

I have an embedded project containing both c files (drivers from the SDK) and c++ (.cpp) files (my own code). I'm trying to set up an interrupt service routine. I've found it works fine if the ISR is in a .c file. However, the exact same function moved into a .cpp file does not work.

In MK64F12_Vector.s;

```
_vectors:
    ...
    .word PORTD_MyIRQHandler
```

Some related initialization code that is called once at start-up;

```
CLOCK_EnableClock(kCLOCK_PortD); 
EnableIRQ(PORTD_IRQn);
PORT_SetPinInterruptConfig(PORTD, 0, kPORT_InterruptFallingEdge);
```

In .c file;

```
void PORTD_MyIRQHandler()
{
  while (1) ; // put breakpoint here
}
```

The above works fine if PORTD_MyIRQHandler() is in a .c file. But if I move it to a .cpp file (where I want it!) I get the error below. Note I am just copying & pasting it without changing anything.

> (.vectors+0x138): undefined reference to `PORTD_MyIRQHandler'

Is there something else I need to do to get it to work? A compiler or linker option perhaps? I've tried the following without success;

```
__attribute__((interrupt)) void PORTD_MyIRQHandler() {..}

#pragma interrupt
void PORTD_MyIRQHandler() {..}
```

I am using Segger Embedded Studio with gcc.

Comment: Are you missing an `extern "C"` in the C++ code?  Name mangling could be the culprit.

Comment: @RobertPrévost yes, that was it. Thanks! If you want to post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: An endless loop in an interrupt handler is an abolute no-go. Said that: you stumbled upon one of the differences between C and C++. Why do you expect two different languages to behave the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
extern "C" void PORTD_MyIRQHandler(){
}
```

C++ adds characters to the fuction name that depend on the input and return value types of the function.

This feature, type name mangling, exists to avoid linking functions with wrong kinds of parameters and to allow function overloading. Using extern "C" disables that.

Comment: This will not magically turn the code in the function into C code. It still will be compiled as C++. See my comment at the question, too.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite : I am not sure what your point is - while true, the answer does not suggest that the resulting code _is_ C.  It gives it C linkage, restricts its interface to be C compatible and in this case allows symbol resolution with the reference in the .s file.  The advantage is that the function _body_ can use C++ specific constructs.